# Extension of definition of supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

Recall that a Dedekind cut is defined as a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying the following three properties:

1. $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A\neq \mathbb{Q}$
2. If $x\in A$, and $y < x$, then $y\in A$
3. For all $x\in A$, there exists $y\in A$ s.t $y > x$

It seems to me, using the Dedekind Cut construction of the real numbers, that the standard way of defining the Supremum Partial Function object, i.e

$\sup (A) = \bigcup A$, defined for all $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with an upper bound and nonempty (a partial function from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$), can easily be modified to a total function, and yet no author ever seems to mention this.

If $\overline{\mathbb{R}} := \mathbb{R} \cup \{\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset\}$, i.e the set of all "pseudo-Dedekind cuts" (with the condition 1 above removed), and the order is again formed from strict inclusion, then $\sup (A) = \bigcup A$ in fact is the least upper bound in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, and forms a total function from $\mathcal{P}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Even for the empty set, the arbitrary union above will return.... the empty set, which is in a sense the least upper bound of nothing: the smallest element of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

I have a few questions.

1. Why is this not how supremum is defined (at least for $\mathbb{R}$?) It seems nicer to say that supremum is a total function from $\mathcal{P}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ than to say that it's a partial function.
2. If we make the very natural symbolic substitution that $\infty = $ the maximum of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, and $-\infty = $the minimum of $\mathbb{R}$, then is it in some sense true that $\infty = \mathbb{Q}$, and $-\infty = \emptyset$?

Comment: Any partial function $f: X \to Y$ can be extended to a total function $g: X \to Y \cup \{\bot\}$, where $g(x) := f(x)$ if $f$ is defined on $x$, and $g(x) = \bot$ otherwise. Here you have one more special case, which is sending the empty set to some other dummy element. But is this really an interesting way to understand a partial function? Does it give any new perspective? I would say that defining sup as a total function to $\{-\infty\} \cup \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ could be useful and consistent, but keep in mind that $\pm \infty$ here are still just formal symbols, like $\bot$.

Comment: Hey, that's kind of exactly what I'm asking about. Here, since we are talking about Dedekind cuts, the entire set of rational numbers would be like \infty, and the empty set would be like -infty. Furthermore, understand that this is a domain extension of sup. Thus, this is not making a function "total" by adding a dummy symbol.